# Make invisible div work inside php loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, mysqli

I'm new to both php and this website so forgive me if this either sounds simple or off-topic. I have fetched data from a mysql database table with 4 columns (id [int], name[varchar], image[varchar] and price[int] with 12 rows. I want to display the data on a page(the image and a button only - This part works) and when i press the button a display box appears that shows more detail(the name and image - This doesn't). If you don't understand what i'm trying to say go to the [amazon website](http://amazon.com) and see how when you press 'quick look' on a product in the homepage it opens a box that shows more detail.
Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
<div id="viewItem">
    <div class="viewItemWrapper">
        <div class="viewContent">
            <div class="text-right" style="cursor:point;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('viewItem');"><strong>X</strong></a></div>
            <div class="text-center"><img id="myTarget" src="" width="320" height="320" alt="Owl Image"></div>
            <div id="product_name"><?php echo $namedeli ?></div>
            <div id="product_price_container">KSh.<span id="product_price"><?php echo $pricedeli?></span></div>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="box_button">
                Add to Cart
                &nbsp &nbsp
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
            </button>
            <div style="float:right; margin-right:25px;"><span style="font-size:1.2em;">Quantity:</span><span id="quantity">0</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$sqldeli = "SELECT * FROM deli";
$resultdeli = mysqli_query($dbc, $sqldeli);

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultdeli) == 12){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultdeli)) {
        $namedeli = $row['name'];
        $imagedeli = $row['image'];
        $pricedeli = $row['price'];

        echo "<div id=\"item\">\n";
        echo "<a href=\"#\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=$imagedeli alt=\"Owl Image\" id=\"homeimage\"></a>\n";
        echo "<a class=\"btn btn-default dropdown-toggle viewbuttons\" onclick='toggle_visibility(\"viewItem\");changeImage($imagedeli);'>View Item</a>\n";
        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
        else{
            echo "Error Connecting";
            }
?>
```

Comment: Your question should be meant by [tag:css] and/or [tag:javascript] not PHP

Comment: Thank you. I'll make the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is very helpful. Take a look on this [live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7nbg92vv/5/)

**CSS**
To hide the detail DIV

```
.hidden_data {display: none;}
```

**The php code to update** the rows

```
...
...
echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<img src="http://www.linkingyourthinking.com/ezine/icon_owl.png" alt="Owl Image"  width="100"/>';
echo '<a href="#" target="" class="active_data btn btn-default dropdown-toggle viewbuttons">';
echo 'View Item 1';
echo  '</a>';
echo '<div class="hidden_data">Item: $namedeli Price: $pricedeli <img src="$imgdeli"></div>';
echo '</div>';
....
```

**The jQuery code**

The jquery code must be at the end of the BODY just after the jquery library. To load jquery library you can use:

```
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var img_a = 'http://www.linkingyourthinking.com/ezine/icon_owl.png';
      var img_b = "http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/220/8/7/owl_png_by_vechy-d5a9ob2.png";


    $(document).on("click", ".active_data", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var item_sel = $(this).parent(".item");
         // restore image
        $(".item img").attr("src", img_a);
        $(".hidden_data").fadeOut(500).promise().done(function(){
            $(item_sel).children(".hidden_data").fadeIn(500);
            // set new image
            $(item_sel).children("img").attr("src", img_b);
        })

    })

})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm happy it help you You could mark it as solved if it is. Just a little note about your html code: id value must be unique, so <div id='item'> in loop is wrong, you should update it to id='item_$unique_value' or switch id to class as i did.